# Facebook Graph API 2.12 Insights Data is Blank

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-insights

```
GET /2.12/158732947xxxx/insights?metric=page_impressions&date_preset=last_year
```

returns the following empty data:

```
    {
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/158732947xxxx/insights?access_token=xxxxxXzZAzGoN2eAZDZD&pretty=0&metric=page_impressions&date_preset=last_year&since=1451721600&until=1483257600",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/158732947xx/insights?access_token=xxxxxWfmC7XzZAzGoN2eAZDZD&pretty=0&metric=page_impressions&date_preset=last_year&since=1514793600&until=1546329600"
  }
}
```

I am using the correct Page Token. I am full Admin and Advertiser admin...

Comment: Did you grant the appropriate permission to read insights …?

Comment: I am admin with full grants I assume...I could not find a way to add read_insights specifically

Comment: The page admin needs to grant this API permission at the time they log in to you app.

Comment: So this would not work in Page Token generated in Graph API Explorer?

Comment: Should work with tokens from there, too - you just need to grant the permission to the app by getting a new user token first.

Comment: Thank you..it worked.. I had to select read_insights for user first

Answer (score 1):

As noted by "CBroe" above, the trick is to get a new token for the user first with read_insights checked..Only after that would the Page Token give the result requested